Clarification on Measure Space in Section 3 of "Integrals with Values in Banach Spaces"
In section 3 of the paper Integrals with Values in Banach Spaces and Locally Convex Spaces by Piotr Mikusiński, the following statement appears:

The space $(,\mathcal{R},)$ can be used to define the space of Lebesgue integrable real-valued functions on $X$ with respect to the extension of $$ to a complete σ-additive measure on $$.

Does this imply that $(,\mathcal{R},)$ is intended to be a measure space? If so, how is this consistent with the fact that $\mathcal{R}$ is described as only being closed under finite (not countable) unions and intersections?
The reference [7] to which the paragraph links is broken, so I cannot follow it in hopes of answering my question.
